# Building Moonlight Trunk - Mono.Cecil.dll

Tags: mono, moonlight

I'm unable to build Mono Moonlight from trunk or from recent tarballs due to the build error below. This happens after Make successfully builds a few other subdirectories:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/MonoTar/moonlight-1.99.5/src'  
Making all in class  
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dev/MonoTar/moonlight-1.99.5/class'  
Making all in .  
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dev/MonoTar/moonlight-1.99.5/class'  
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `/home/dev/MonoTar/mcs/class/lib/net_1_1  /Mono.Cecil.dll', needed by `lib/tuner/Mono.Cecil.dll'.  Stop.  
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/MonoTar/moonlight-1.99.5/class'  
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/MonoTar/moonlight-1.99.5/class'  
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/MonoTar/moonlight-1.99.5'  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Whether with tarballs or svn checkout, I am placing mono, mcs, libgdiplus, and moon in the same directory. Then:

```
cd mono  
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr  
make  
sudo make install  
cd ../libgdiplus  
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr  
make  
sudo make install  
cd ../moon  
./configure --prefix=/usr  
make
```

And I get this error about Mono.Cecil.dll. Any ideas about why? Configure from moon shows no errors and the final configuration look like this below, in case it helps (I've tried with and without the --with-mcspath option):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-mcspath=/home/dev/MonoTar/mcs/  
Moonlight configuration  
=======================  

  General configuration:  
    Using cairo: embedded  
    Test Harness: no (reason: failed to find xtst >= 1.0)  
    Performance Suite: no (reason: performance suite requires FF3)  

  Debug configuration:  
    Sanity checks: no  
    Object tracking: no  
    Logging support with MOONLIGHT_DEBUG: yes  

  Media Support:   
    FFmpeg: no (reason: could not find libavutil and libavcodec packages)  
    ALSA: no (reason: could not find alsa development package)  
    PulseAudio: no (reason: could not find libpulse development package)  

  Silverlight Support:  
    Silverlight 1.0: yes  
    Silverlight 2.0: yes  
          Browser plugin assemblies: yes   
            Path to mcs tree: /home/dev/MonoTar/mcs/  
            Path to mono-basic tree: no  
          Desktop application assemblies: yes   

  Browser Support:  
    Firefox: yes  
          Plugin Installer (.xpi): yes  
          Gecko 1.8 (Firefox 2): yes   
          Gecko 1.9 (Firefox 3): no (reason: missing FF3 development packages)
```

Is anyone successfully compiling the moonlight plugin themselves on any Linux distro? Any advice?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Moonlight 2.0 we'll be using mono's 2.6 branch from here:

http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/branches/mono-2-6/

mono trunk is going through a lot of unstable changes right now, which is why we decided to use the stable 2.6 branch instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think Moonlight currently uses a branch of mono and mcs, so it might be best to use that -  or it might just be a makfile bug in mcs trunk. You'd be best asking on the moonlight mailing list or IRC.

Answer (score 0):

For such specific questions about building moonlight, please join us on irc.gnom.org/#moonlight or our mailing list moonlight-list @ lists.ximian.com. We can better help you that way.